# How do I reorder plot by multiple variables?

Tags: plotnine

I am trying to reorder plot first by `am` and then by `mpg`. Attached in the result in R using ggplot2.

I trying to attain the same result using siuba and plotnine. Below is my code so far.

```
(
mtcars 
    >> arrange(_.am, _.mpg)
    >> mutate(model = fct_reorder(_.model, _.am))
    >> ggplot(aes(y="mpg", x="model", fill='factor(am)'))
    + geom_col()
    + labs(fill = "Automatic/Manual Transmission")
    + coord_flip()
)
```

[image: example]

Comment: ![example](https://imgur.com/a/yK6TJv9)

Answer (score 2):

If I should replicate your plot in R I would make use of `dplyr::arrange` + `forcats::fct_inorder`. As `siuba` does not offer an equivalent to `fct_inorder` you could achieve your desired result by first arranging in your desired order, adding an index column of row numbers and reordering by this index column:

```
from plotnine import *
from siuba import _, arrange, mutate
from siuba.dply.forcats import fct_reorder
(
mtcars 
    >> arrange(-_.am, _.mpg)
    >> mutate(model = fct_reorder(_.model, _.reset_index().index))
    >> ggplot(aes(y="mpg", x="model", fill='factor(am)'))
    + geom_col()
    + labs(fill = "Automatic/Manual Transmission")
    + coord_flip()
)
```

[image]